# Connection string issue in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

I have the following connection string class

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DBConnection
    Sub GetConnection()
        Dim CrmsConn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("crmsConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    End Sub

End Class
```

And I have tried to call the connection string from the above class as follows:

```
 Dim dbcon As DBConnection
Dim con As New SqlConnection(dbcon.GetConnection())
```

But it has an error near dbcon.GetConnection(). 
What is the solution?

Comment: In future consider including the error. There are a couple of errors that could potentially occur. I've removed the dupe link as the answer provided solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetConnection is a sub. This means that it doesn't return anything and you cannot try to use an inexistant return value. (This is a compile time error, you can't produce any executable code until you fix it)

Make it a function and public

```
Public Function GetConnection() as SqlConnection
    return New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("crmsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
End Function
```

and then use it as (but create the class instance first otherwise a null reference exception occurs at runtime)

```
' Create the instance of the DBConnection class and ...
Dim dbcon As DBConnection = new DBConnection()

' ... get the connection
Dim con as SqlConnection = dbcon.GetConnection()
```

Finally remember to use the Using statement around disposable objects like this

```
Using con = dbCon.GetConnection()
    ....
End Using
```

Comment: Works helpful description.